# Error when running python script from startup on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, startup, pynput

I want to run a python script on startup and it uses Pynput:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
```

When I put the script in rc.local or run it on startup from .sh, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/controlsAndServer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError: this platform is not supported: ('failed to acquire X connection: Bad display name ""', DisplayNameError(''))

Try one of the following resolutions:

 * Please make sure that you have an X server running, and that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
```

I have double checked and everything should be installed/updated. I made the file executable as well. If someone could advise me of the issue it would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You generally can't use X applications until after a user has logged in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autostart a kivy gui on a raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546028/autostart-a-kivy-gui-on-a-raspberry-pi)